# Passing array as function parameter, and calling begin/end methods on it

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int vowels[] = {65, 69, 73, 79, 85, 97, 101, 105, 111, 117}; // ASCII codes (upper & lower case).

bool characterInArray(char letter, int arr[]) {
  return find(begin(arr), end(arr), (int) letter) != end(arr);
}

int main() {
  if (characterInArray('i', vowels)) {
    cout << "Found a vowel in the character provided." << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Given this code, I'm given an error "error: no matching function for call to "begin". The full error message is below, what am I doing wrong here?

```
candidate template ignored: could not match 'initializer_list<type-parameter-0-0>' against 'int *'
```

Comment: *Passing array as function parameter* -- In your code, you are actually passing a pointer to the first element, not the array.  So your function is no different than `bool characterInArray(char letter, int *arr)`.  That should explain the error you're getting.

Comment: Instead of using numbers like 65, use `'A'` etc. It's much clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, a function parameter like `int arr[]` is *adjusted* to `int* arr`, which is why `begin()` and `end()` don't work. You can solve this by passing a reference to an array `const int (&arr)[10]`, but it may be simpler to drop the function and just call `any_of` with the right predicate,

```
if (any_of(begin(vowels), end(vowels),
    [](char c) { return c == 'i'; }) { ... }
```